# Using parameters in a Restlet Client Request

Tags: http, parameters, client, restlet

I have:

```
Request request = new Request(Method.GET, "https://www.awebsite.com/login");
Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTPS);
Response response = client.handle(request);
...
response.getEntity().write(System.out);
```

But I don't know how to set the login parameters...

I want code that

- does the escaping etc
- can switch between get/post easily

---

Being a REST-based platform, I'm thinking I might need to use some parameter "representation" but that seems a bit strange.  I'd think it would be common enough to build in this representational exception.

Comment: Restlet is a Java framework for building and working with RESTful web applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "login parameters" you mean sending credentials using [Basic HTTP Authentication,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) it's done using [Request.setChallengeResponse()](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/api/org/restlet/data/Request.html#setChallengeResponse(org.restlet.data.ChallengeResponse)) like so:

```
Request request = new Request(Method.GET, "https://www.awebsite.com/login");
request.setChallengeResponse(new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, username, password));
```

This will work for any Request, using any HTTP method.

If, however, the server to which you're trying to authenticate expects credentials using some protocol other than Basic HTTP Auth, then you'll need to explain that protocol -- i.e. does it use cookies, headers, tokens, etc.

BTW, you might get faster/better responses by posting to the [Restlet-Discuss](http://www.restlet.org/community/lists) mailing list; I've been on there for a year and a half and it's a great community.